# How can I take a tag full of text and turn it into a list of what I want?

Tags: python, html, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse 100 ways to say "I love you" in a different language. I am using this website http://thecircular.org/say-i-love-you-in-100-languages/.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page1 = requests.get('http://thecircular.org/say-i-love-you-in-100-languages/')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser')


ILY = soup1.find('ol')

for tag in ILY.find_all("li"):
   print(tag.text)
```

my output is :

```
Arabic – Ana behibek (to female)
Armenian – Yes kez sirumen
Bambara – M’bi fe
Bangla – Aamee tuma ke bhalo aashi
etc...
```

I would like to get just the word "I love you" without the country and the hypen

Desired output:

```
("Ana behibek" , "Yes kez sirumen", "M’bi fe", "Aamee tuma ke bhalo aashi", etc...)
```

EDIT:

New Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page1 = requests.get('http://thecircular.org/say-i-love-you-in-100-languages/')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1.content, 'html.parser')

ILY = soup1.find('ol')
iLoveYou = tuple([tag.text.split('-')[0] for tag in ILY.find_all("li")])

print(iLoveYou)
```

I used the .split method with list comprehension. However it returns

```
('Arabic – Ana behibek (to female)', 'Armenian – Yes kez sirumen', 'Bambara – M’bi fe')
```

The output I would like is

```
('Ana behibek', 'Yes kez sirumen', 'M’bi fe')
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `.split` and `.strip` methods with list comprehension

```py
t = tuple([tag.text.split('–')[1].strip() for tag in ILY.find_all("li")])
```

Comment: it gives this error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I fixed it, I changed the "[1]" to a "[0]" however it gives me the whole list with the countries "('Arabic – Ana behibek (to female)', 'Armenian – Yes kez sirumen', 'Bambara – M’bi fe')" I would like to just have the language

Comment: it seems like `-` in the page looks exactly like the usual one but isn't the same, I updated the answer